# (Lua) How do I find the tail of a custom linked list?

Tags: lua

I have a linked list defined like that:

```
list = nil
list = {next=nil, value=value}
```

So I am trying to find the tail of the list and append an element to it:

```
function appendToBack(list, value)
  local list = list
  if not list then 
    list = {next=nil, value=value}
  else
    local next = list.next
    while true do
      if not next then
        next = {next=nil, value=value}
        break
      else
        next = next.next
      end
    end
  end

  return list
end
```

How do I find the last/any node of a custom linked list with a function like that?

Comment: What's the question here exactly?

Comment: look at the line `next = {next=nil, value=value}`; it's only assigning a local variable. What you need to do is assign the `next` field of the last node of the list.

Comment: @EtanReisner How do I traverse a linked list and append a new node at the end?

Comment: @Diego How do I get that last node? I cannot figure out that.

Comment: That function *is* traversing the linked list. It is also creating a new tail element but as @Diego indicated it is failing to link the new element into the current last element of the list.

Comment: @EtanReisner I know that. Thanx! :) But I utterly fail to get it around my head and do what you are suggesting. Part of the problem is that I am a Lua noob. I already tried various things. Maybe I have to leave it for later.

Comment: [Code review to help you understand what you are doing] 1) A good IDE would flag `list = nil` with, "The value assigned is not used. Consider deleting the assignment". 2) `local list = list` doesn't do anything but shadow the original `list` variable (the parameter, which is effectively a local variable). Of course, those statements have be dropped in the answers.

Answer (score 2):

To find the last node in the list you do something like this:

```
function last (list)
  -- Just checking...
  if list == nil then
    return nil
  end

  -- We start at the first node...
  local node = list
  -- ...while there's a next...
  while node.next ~= nil do
    -- ... we move to it
    node = node.next
  end
  -- when we reach this line, node variable holds the
  -- last element in the list
  return node
end
```

It is similar to your function but here the iteration never passes through the end of the list (i.e. `node` variable is never `nil`). You could write a recursive version of the `last` function if you want; it will be a bit simpler :-)

Now that you have a `last` function, in your `appendToBack`, the else branch could read:

```
last (list).next = { value = value }
```

Answer (score 1):

The list will have the following structure:

```
list = { -- [1]
  value = 'list head',
  next = { -- [2]
    value = 'list node',
    next = { -- [3]
      value = 'list tail',
    },
  },
}
```

The tail of a list is the first node where `next` is `nil` (i.e. node 3 above). Find the list tail by looping and updating the reference to tail when it has a valid next node. Once `tail.next` is `nil` the value of `tail` is the end of the list.

```
local tail = list
while tail.next do
  tail = tail.next
end
tail.next = { value=value }
```